# Let $ A $ be a $ n \times n $ matrix. Show that over the complex numbers

Tags: matrices

Let $ A $ be a $ n \times n $ matrix. Show that over the complex numbers , there exists an invertible matrix P such that $ P^{-1}AP$ is an upper triangular matrix.

**Answer:**  If  the matrix $A $ is diagonalisable then $ P^{-1}AP $ is diagonal and hence it is an upper triangualr matrix. Now if $ A $ is not diagonalisable , then $ P^{-1} AP $ has **Jordan canonical form** , which is upper triangular. Hence the proof .   **Is it  right approach ?** **Any help**

Comment: Can you justify why $A$ has a Jordan form?

Comment: since every matrix  has jordan form

Comment: I meant, how do you know that? Otherwise you're just shifting the claim.

Comment: i can't justify right now , but i know one think  that -a matrix may not  not be diagonalisable  but it is similar to a jordan form .

Comment: Am I right ? or wrong

Comment: While the existence of a Jordan canonical form suffices to show your claim, it does seem a possibly oversimplified approach.  It depends on how much you were expected to do for this problem.

Comment: The existence of Jordan form is very hard to prove.  Much harder than proving this result directly.  If I was your professor I would not allow using Jordan form.

Answer (score 2):

Because $C$ is algebraically closed, $A$ has a nonzero eigenvector $v$. Rewriting $A$ relative to any basis $(v,w_2,\dots,w_n)$, we see that $A$ is similar to a block-matrix of the form $\pmatrix{\lambda & B \\ 0 & A_1}$, where $A_1$ is some $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. Now, considering the action of $A_1$ on the subspace generated by $w_2, \dots, w_n,$ the desired result can be obtained by induction on $n$.

Comment: Ah yes, the ***Schur Decomposition***: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition!

Comment: And with a little more work, one can show that $P$ is ***unitary***.  Can you?

Comment: In that case, choose the subspace $(w_2, \dots, w_n)$ to be orthogonal to $v$ at each stage of the argument.